# Cannot access a closed stream while sending attachment

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I'm trying to send email with attachment using C#. Here is my method:

```
public void SendEmail(string from, string to, SmtpClient client)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to, "Otrzymałeś nowe zamówienie od "+from , "Przesyłam nowe zamówienie na sprzęt");
        mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        // Adding attachment:

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
        writer.Write("Hello its my sample file");
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Dispose();

        System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
        attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.txt";

        mm.Attachments.Add(attach);
        try
        {
            client.Send(mm);
        }
        catch(SmtpException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        ms.Close();
    }
```

stacktrace points to this line:

```
client.Send(mm);
```

problem is caused by this line:

```
writer.Dispose();
```

Why I can not dispose this element right after using it to write into `MemoryStream`?
This element isn't used any time later in the code.

Comment: why not try `using` block.

Comment: The Dispose of the streamwriter ALSO disposes the underlying stream.  Call the writer.Dispose AFTER the email has been sent.

Comment: I found that, when operating on `Stream` objects, the `using` keyword is extremely useful. As @HassanNisar mentioned, try it. It will make the code a lot more readable and you should be able to avoid the exception you're getting at the moment.

Comment: As rene mentioned, closing or disposing a StreamWriter, also closes the underlying basestream (the memorystream in this case). If you need to reuse the same memorystream, you can dispose after sending, as suggested, or if you're using .net 4.5, you can create a streamwriter that leaves the basestream open with the following constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg712853%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling Dispose on the writer also Disposes the underlying stream. You have to dispose both the writer and the stream after the email has been sent. You can achieve that by wrapping your code in two using statements.

```
    using(var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
      using(var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms))
      {
         writer.Write("Hello its my sample file");
         writer.Flush();

         System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
         System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
         attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.txt";

         mm.Attachments.Add(attach);
         try
         {
             client.Send(mm);
         }
         catch(SmtpException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: But how does that work if you have multiple attachments?

Comment: @RayCW well, prepare all streams, keep track of them in a list or array if you don't know how much you have of them, call Attachments.Add for each stream, Send the email and once completed call dispose on all your wiriters.and streams in your List or Array. The using might no longer be useful in that case, just expand to a try/catch/finally.

Comment: @YogeshSharma no, there is barely enough info to diagnose that. Feel free to ask a new question, assuming you follow [ask] and are capable to create an [mcve] that demonstrates your specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use using block, like suggested in the comments:

```
//...
using(System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{   
    using(System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        writer.Write("Hello its my sample file");
        writer.Flush();

        System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
        attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.txt";

        mm.Attachments.Add(attach);
        client.Send(mm);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `client.Send` tries to send it will obviously read `Attachment` which points to a `MemoryStream` which has be already closed by `StreamWriter`. You can verify this by inspecting `ms.CanRead` It will return false.

Accessing closed stream will throw exception, that's what you're experiencing. To solve it just get rid of `writer.Dispose()`as there is nothing to dispose with `MemoryStream` or dispose it after you completed your job.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several attachments, you need every stream open, which is so 2001.

Today all you have to do is this:

```
var attachments = new List<Attachment>();    
attachments.Add(Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(STRING, 
"Title.xml",  Encoding.Unicode, "text/xml"));
```

...

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage { From = "....", Subject = ... };

foreach (var attachment in attachments)
{
   mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
};
```

No stream. No hassle. Just a bunch of attachments.

You can use text/csv as well